# Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL

Tags: java, http, soapui

When I create a new SOAP project in SoapUI 4.6.4, first I have to add initial WSDL url. My initial WSDL URL: `http://l:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?wsdl`.

But I'm getting this error:

> Error loading `http://lxxxxxxxx?wsdl`:
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: java.io.IOException: Server returned
>   HTTP response code: 405 for URL: `http://lxxxxxxxx?wsdl`

So how can I fix this?

Comment: HTTP 405 means method is not allowed, so probably the problem is that your server not allows GET on http://lxxxxxxxxxxxx?wsdl to retrieve your wsdl. Or maybe your wsdl url is in a different location, i.e when you deploy a WS with some frameworks the wsdl location can be http://lxxxxxxxxxxxx?wsdl=...

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit and include the context path of your query? If you're trying to GET http://1xxxxxxxx?wsdl instead of http://1xxxxxxxx/somepath?wsdl then I'm not surprised that it's not working. It would be rare for a WS to exist in the root context of a host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response Code 405: method Not Allowed
one of the Methods GET/POST is disallowed, and you are using one of them
[check this](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html)

Answer (score 1):

405 is method not allowed error, this mean you have method that causing problem when its being called. Check if you have duplicate path with method in your wsdl. If no duplicate path try open the h`ttp://lxxxxxxxxxxxx?wsdl` in your browser if you cant, that`s mean something wrong with your web configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here are correct but difficult to get for those who are new in this like me. So in simple try changing your controller's request mapping.

*@RequestMapping(path = RequestMappingURL.IVPS_CYCLE_DATE, method = {
            RequestMethod.POST }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)*

**In above code I mapped request method as post but actually client was sending get request. As soon as I changed it to GET it worked. See below code**

*@RequestMapping(path = RequestMappingURL.IVPS_CYCLE_DATE, method = {
            RequestMethod.GET }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)*