# (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse() returns an error on all request and too slow on second request but fast in other request

Tags: c#, fileserver

I have 4 file upload controls in my website, each of them will access my file server using `(HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse()` the **first** upload is fast, but the **second** upload is very slow, but the **third and fourth** upload is fast also. All the files are the same. I use `(System.Net.HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();` because I want to access/get response a folder in that server.

I check my logs and it turns out that the **all** upload returns an error `The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.` So why in the **second** upload is slower, it took 20 seconds to get the response, but the rest of request is like a second.

This is my original code:

```
try
{
      Response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
      Response.Close();
}
      catch (Exception)
{
```

I already tried setting my `Request.Proxy` to `null` and also

```
using (Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse())
{
}
```

and also

```
<system.net>
 <connectionManagement>
   <add address="*" maxconnection="20"/>
 </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

and also

```
httpWebRequest.Abort();
```

So it turns out that `(System.Net.HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();` return an error. How do i close it?

Comment: Do you get 405 for requests 2,3 and 4?

Comment: Yes, i got an error of 405 to all of the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 405 responses for each request then for the moment you ought to concentrate your efforts on understanding why your requests to the file server are not allowed.

Are there other end-points on that server you can access? Do you have permissions to access that server?

This link to HttpStatus codes explains a little more about what the 405 means https://httpstatuses.com/405

The answers to this Stackoverflow question might get you started with regards to investigating your problem. [Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299707/server-returned-http-response-code-405-for-url)

**EDIT**

I'm also not certain as to why you say using Request.GetResponse creates a folder?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm getting 405 errors on all request (Same files are being uploaded), but the first, third and fourth upload is fast, while the second upload is slower. Why the second upload is slow even if they are all 405 error when using `(System.Net.HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();`? I think the problem is not in the method im using?

Comment: I dont have actual access on the file server i am using, but the files are uploaded successfully. I always call the `(System.Net.HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();` to create a folder (Same name) when uploading a file

Comment: How do you know your files are uploaded successfully? Are the files distinct from each other?.

Comment: I access it via url. Yes it is distinct to each other. I added timestamp in the end of each filename.

Comment: Sorry for that. This is my request code `Request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(directory);`

Comment: and then Request.Method = 'MKCOL' to create a folder